# Problem with HDMI on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, hdmi

I've a problem with HDMI on my ultrabook.
One week ago it worked fine but now there is a problem.
When I connect it, Ubuntu recognize the monitor-tv but it's black/blank, no image will display.
Someone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's try and see if Ubuntu knows the second monitor.
Open the Dash and type "Display". Enter the program and you should see 2 monitors there, one your laptop and the other your monitor connected trough HDMI.
Click on the external monitor and make sure it is set to "ON".

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes the second monitor/tv is set to ON

Comment: You say it worked for you, did you made some modifications to the drivers or something?

Comment: no @Rat2000, with VGA it works fine.